# Android Google Analytics compile error "Could not find class"

Tags: android, google-analytics

I have called:

> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.5.0'

When I run project I get an error:

Log cat :

> 06-26 15:39:17.563    2415-2415/com.demo E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.demo.utils.logger.ChainedLogNode', referenced from
>   method com.demo.utils.logger.Logger.initialize.

When I remove `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.5.0'`, it runs ok.

Stop app :

> 6-26 15:39:17.579    2415-2415/com.demo.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>           java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.demo.utils.logger.ChainedLogNode
>                   at com.demo.utils.logger.Logger.initialize(Logger.java:150)
>                   at com.demo.utils.CommonUtil.setupLoggers(CommonUtil.java:3215)
>                   at com.demo.DemoApplication.onCreate(DemoApplication.java:103)
>                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:999)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4151)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:130)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1255)
>                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: post some code please

Comment: i import compile. it errors.

Comment: try syncing the project before trying to run the app with compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.5.0'

Comment: i have work same . but no success.